# Implement Security To WPF XBAP in ASP.NET

Tags: asp.net, wpf

I am loading WPF pages using XBAP URL in to ASP.NET Application.My web app is secured using forms authentication,In my app iam calling XBAP url internally .The XBAP url can be accessed by any Anonymous users.I want to make it secure,because when you internally call a URL it is stored in browser history. so XBAP can be assessed by any Anonymous user from history with out logging into app.Please can anyone let me know how can we maintain security for XBAP.